# Failed to run init method on using GenServer

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am new to elixir and recently found that `GenServer` is a good way to manage client/server API. So I tried to create a GenServer module to manage database connection but failed. Below is my code:

```
defmodule RedisClient do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  # Client
  def start(url) do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, {url})
  end

  def init({url}) do
    Logger.info("connect to url #{url}");
    case Redix.start_link(url) do
        {:ok, conn} -> {conn}
        {:error, err} -> {:error, err}
    end
  end

end
```

The module `RedisClient` is used to connect to a redis database in its init() method. But it returns below error:

```
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)15> RedisClient.start("redis://localhost")
{:error, {:bad_return_value, {#PID<0.6623.0>}}}
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)16> 
17:58:20.592 [info]  connect to url redis://localhost

nil
```

I don't understand why it returns an error and why it prints `nil` at the end. It works fine if I call `Redis` directly as below:

```
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)17> Redix.start_link("redis://localhost")
{:ok, #PID<0.7443.0>}
```

It seems that the API call on `Redix` has no problem, so what wrong with my GenServer implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `{:ok, state}` from `init/1` on success:

```
{:ok, conn} -> {:ok, conn}
```

or since you're returning exactly what `Redix.start_link` returns, you can simply return that:

```
def init({url}) do
  Logger.info("connect to url #{url}");
  Redix.start_link(url)
end
```